# Unable to redirect form submission page to php

Tags: php, html

I am Unable to redirect form submission page to php.When i click submit it displays me the PHP page, i am looking out for a code were the form can be saved on a particular location & after clicking subit the user needs to get Thank You message & the mail should get send to me itself

My Code as below:

HTML

```
<html>
<title>
Test
</title>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test2.php"> onsubmit="return"
<center>
<font color="FFFFFF">From: <br><input name="email"type="text"></font>
</center>
<br>
<center>
<font color="FFFFFF">SSL Request:<br><textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></font>
</center>
<br>
<center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request!">
</center>
</form>
<br>
This is test form
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$to = "abc@yahoo.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email";
$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: you@youremailaddress.com\n";
$usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list.";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
?>
```

Comment: 01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
01:35:53 AM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: Below is the error while starting Apache service through XAMPP

Comment: Sidenote: Your code seems to be broken `<form method="post" action="test2.php"> onsubmit="return"`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are accessing php file without running on web server.

to run PHP code we needs to have a PHP supporting web server such as XAMPP (free server collection) or WAMP. after installing server, put your php files in to htdocs folder and then access your file through web server links.

you cannot directly run PHP codes without Server.

this tutorial may help you.
https://www.udemy.com/blog/xampp-tutorial/

Comment: Getting error 1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
1:04:10 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: are you have installed vmware, IIS or any web server? those softwares owns port 80. then you cannot start apache. try the find software which using port 80 and stop it. then start server..